# Send notification E-Mail to x when x’s content is commented

Tags: 7, comments, notifications

How to notify an author of a node, when her content is commented by another user on Drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Create the following Rule:

1. Event: after saving a new comment. You will probably want to restrict this by content type as well.
2. Add action: send mail. Arguments:

   - To: switch to data selection and choose `comment:node:author:mail`
   - Subject: whatever you want, for example "A comment has been posted to your blog post"
   - Add the message
   - Condition: NOT `comment:node:author:uid` and `comment:author:uid` so that the user does not receive emails for his own comments.

Here's how to insert the name of the node author:

Formatted username:

```
Dear [comment:node:author:name], [...]
```

Specific field (e.g. if you have first and last name fields and you want to use only first name):

```
Dear [comment:node:author:field-first-name], [...]
```

Comment: Wow that was simple and works like a charm. One question left: How to insert the name of the node author in the e-mail? Like: Dear X, your entry has been commented.

Comment: Answer updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does indeed. Much apreciated. I go with this solution. However It appeares that if I comment on my own post I get an e-mail nontheless. So I added the folowing condition:
    NOT Data comparison
    Parameter: Data to compare: [comment:node:author:uid], Data value: [comment:author:uid]
Do you think this is the right way to do that?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, that's the way to do it. I'll update my answer shortly.